# SQL How to join these three views into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to I join the following two views? I have tried by myself but they always break, and display repeated data. The only work around I could think of was to create two views and then a third one to join the two views. The issue is that for my application I would then have approx 10 views, which is not efficient nor correctly designed.

**View 1**

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, GROUP_CONCAT(email SEPARATOR ', ') AS array_emails
FROM entity AS e
LEFT JOIN emails ON e.id=emails.entity_id
GROUP BY id;
```

**View 2**

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, GROUP_CONCAT(web_site SEPARATOR ', ') AS array_web_sites
FROM entity AS e
LEFT JOIN web_sites ON e.id=web_sites.entity_id
GROUP BY id
```

**View 3** (this view joins view 1 and 2 together)

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, view_web_sites.array_web_sites, view_emails.array_emails
FROM entity AS e
LEFT JOIN view_web_sites ON e.id=view_web_sites.id
LEFT JOIN view_emails ON e.id=view_emails.id
GROUP BY id
```

This was my original view, which didnt work correctly. The values would repeat.

**Original - broken view**
    SELECT e.id, e.name, GROUP_CONCAT(email SEPARATOR ',') AS emails,
    GROUP_CONCAT(web_site SEPARATOR ',') AS web_sites
    FROM entity AS e
    LEFT JOIN emails ON e.id=emails.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN web_sites ON e.id=web_sites.entity_id
    GROUP BY id;

EDIT:
I have already explored the distinct argument in the select statement, which works great. However in one table I have a binary column and the distinct argument "erases" the value, rendering the column useless. Any suggestions on this matter?

EDIT #2 (FIX):
I managed to solve the issue for anyone who might be facing a similar issue.

```
SELECT entity.id, entity.name,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(emails.email) FROM emails WHERE entity.id=emails.entity_id) AS emails_array,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(web_sites.web_site) FROM web_sites WHERE
entity.id=web_sites.entity_id) AS websites_array
FROM entity
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT m.email SEPARATOR ', ') AS array_emails,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.web_site SEPARATOR ', ') AS array_web_sites
FROM entity AS e
  LEFT JOIN emails AS m ON e.id = m.entity_id
  LEFT JOIN web_sites AS w ON e.id = w.entity_id
GROUP by e.id ;
```

If you use the views, you don't need the last `GROUP BY id`:

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.name, 
       m.array_emails,
       w.array_web_sites
FROM entity AS e
  LEFT JOIN view_emails AS m ON e.id = m.entity_id
  LEFT JOIN view_web_sites AS w ON e.id = w.entity_id ;
```

If you don't want nested views, you could write it using one query - and simplify it by removing the joins inside the derived tables:

```
SELECT e.id, 
       e.name, 
       m.array_emails,
       w.array_web_sites
FROM entity AS e
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT entity_id, 
             GROUP_CONCAT(email SEPARATOR ', ') AS array_emails
      FROM emails
      GROUP BY entity_id 
    ) AS m ON e.id = m.entity_id
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT entity_id, 
             GROUP_CONCAT(web_site SEPARATOR ', ') AS array_web_sites
      FROM web_sites
      GROUP BY entity_id 
    ) AS w ON e.id = w.entity_id ;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i had tested the distinct argument already. it works great but the only issue is that i have a column in a table which has a binary value, and when i use distinct it gets "erased".
any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean with "erased"?

Comment: well lets say i have 4 records in the column which has a binary value,
record 1: 0
record 2: 0
record 3: 0
record 4: 1

the distinct argument along with the GROUP_CONCAT() converts it into: 0, 1. And not 0, 0, 0, 1 (due to the distinct arg.)
but the issue is that when i dont have the distinct value, my output is 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 (loops it 3 times, because i have other tables that repeat as well) which is why the only solution that worked for me was make a view for each table, then join all the views together again in the final view.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was afraid that the two versions may return different results because of such data. Then you can use the 2nd query, either as it is, with nested views, or with derived tables.